# Why sys_mmap is not present in syscalls.h file in Android 2.6.29?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

In `syscalls.h` file of Android 2.6.29, there is `unmap` sys call but not `mmap`.

Is there any reason for not including `mmap` in `syscalls.h` file?

Answer (score 0):

How possible?

Check out:
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.29/arch/x86/include/asm/syscalls.h#L87

```
  87 asmlinkage long sys_mmap(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long,
  88                         unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long);
```

Comment: I was actually working on Android (Linux 2.6.29) and assumed that both Android and Linux have the same set of system calls. And in my android source code, sys_mmap() is still not there. :)

Comment: You didn't even mention this... maybe android removes it.

Comment: my mistake. I am sorry. I should have put that down there. Updated the question